# ElasticSearch incorrectly indexing and querying on non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: string, normalization, elasticsearch

My ElasticSearch index is not correctly indexing and querying non-alphanumeric characters.  Specifically, dots and dashes are causing problems.

If I index a document with the name "O.K. Corral," it should match queries for "OK Corral". Similarly, if I index "Whiskey A Go-Go," I'd like it to match "Whiskey A GoGo" and "Whiskey A Go Go".

Right now, only queries with the correct dots and dashes will return these documents.

I'm hoping the solution will also solve any potential problems with other non-alphanumeric characters, like commas and apostrophes.

It sounds like a job for ElasticSearch token filters, but I haven't been able to find one that does what I'm looking for.  Also, I would like to do this within ElasticSearch -- I don't want to write custom string manipulations to normalize data before it gets to my ES index.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have a look at the word delimiter filter, it should do at least some of the things that you need.

Comment: @javanna Looks like word delimiter does what I want with dashes -- now it's just those pesky dots.  Thanks!

Comment: Great, I just added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to have a look at the [Word Delimiter Token Filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html). It will at least do what you want with "Whiskey A GoGo" and "Whiskey A Go-Go,". You can check its behaviour in advance using the [analyze api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-analyze.html).

Comment: As it turns out, the word delimiter token filter also handled my problem with dots.  One thing I had to remember was to take off the standard tokenizer -- if that is in place, the strings will already be tokenized (incorrectly in my case) before they get to the filter.  But by using the whitespace tokenizer, and a properly configured word delimiter token filter, I was able to get everything working just right.  Thanks!